# Finding Repo Branch Token

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

When working with the Security APIs for Repositories, the various branches are referenced with an alphanumeric identifier that is derived from the "human" name of the branch.

This identifier is the last portion of the token. For example, the master branch, the identifier is always `6d0061007300740065007200`.  This is not a GUID that is assigned by the back end system, but a calculated value

I've looked through the API documentation and have not been able to find any way to look up this identifier.

Just wondering if I'm missing something or looking in the wrong place?  Does anyone know if there's a place to find this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rough function written in PowerShell, but it works to convert a branch name to the requisite hex code.

```
Function get-AzDoBranchTokenFromName {  
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Convert branch name to token

    .DESCRIPTION
    Azure DevOps Services security stores Access Control Lists and other items
    for Branches using a alphanumeric identifier derived from the text name of
    the branch.  This function will convert the name, like "master", into the 
    appropriate string, like 6d0061007300740065007200

    .PARAMETER branchName
    The human name of the git repository branch

    .EXAMPLE
    get-AzDoBranchTokenFromName -branchName "master"

    .NOTES
    The fun part is trying to go backwards (from hex to string).  Need to 
    work on that yet. 
    #>

    param(  
        # The sting you wish to Convert
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $branchName   
    )
    # convert a string to an array of bytes    
    $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($branchName)    
    # create a new variable twice as long as $bytes
    $Hex = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new($Bytes.Length * 2)    
    # take each byte, format it as two hex characters and shove it into $Hex
    ForEach ($byte in $bytes) {      
        if ($byte -eq 47) {
            #Write-Output "YATZEE!!!!"
            $Hex.Append("/") | Out-Null
        }else{
        $Hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", $byte) | Out-Null    
        }
    }
    # convert $Hex back to a string    
    $Hex.ToString()
}
```